# Connecting to TCPListener from browser creates multiple TCPClients instead of one

Tags: tcplistener

I have TCPListener server based on this source code https://gist.github.com/leandrosilva/656054#file-server-cs

I created a server on port 3340. Whenever a client connects to the server, then server waits for the new client connection. When I connect from my Chrome browser to the server, then it seems there are three clients connected (expected only one). [image: Resource monitor shows server has three connections]
Why it is like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most clients maintain multiple connections in parallel, including more than one connection per server endpoint.

And RFC7230 section-6.4 explains. Multiple connections are typically used to avoid the "head-of-line blocking" problem

Comment: Ok, now it is clear. But how can I handle this situation in my server application?

Comment: @oarar There is no special way to do this in server.